# Have you ever negative form

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I have to create negative question in present perfect:

[image]

I know how to ask positive question, it will be:

> "Have you ever paid a bill?"

But the task says "not pay" so should I ask:

> "Have you ever didn't pay a bill?"

I guess I cannot ask

> "Haven't you ever ..."

because it will be another meaning.

So to do this exercise I have to use never/ever it's necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you never paid the bill, Haven't you ever paid a bill

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between

> Haven't you ever paid a bill?

and

> Have you ever not paid a bill?

The first one asks if you have never ever paid bills. The second one asks if you, at one time or another, did not pay a bill.

Both sentences are correct; I'm just not sure which one they want to hear ;)

By the way, you can use sentences with "Did" if you want.

> Didn't you ever pay a bill?

and

> Did you ever not pay a bill?

But you can't use "have" and "did" in the same sentence.

Comment: "Have you ever not paid a bill?" That's what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Side comment: The first person singular pronoun must always be spelled with the capital letter **I**, not with the small letter **i**.

---

> "Have you ever paid a bill?"

is correct

---

> "Have you ever didn't pay a bill?"

is definitely not correct, using both "have" and "did" together with "pay".

---

> "Haven't you ever ..."

may be correct, depending on what will follow.

---

The following are both correct:

> - **Have** you **never** paid a bill?
> - **Haven't** you **ever** *paid* a bill?

---

But the **image** in the question uses **"has"**, so I assume it should be in the **3rd person singular**:

> - **Has** he **never** paid a bill?
> - **Hasn't** she **ever** *paid* a bill?

Comment: “Paid” instead of “pay” should follow “ever”, otherwise I agree with the highlighted sentences.

Comment: The mother of copy and paste! Of course you are right :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You said the positive question was:

> "Have you ever paid a bill?"

This is asking if you have, at any time in the past, paid *any* bill (because it uses the indefinite article).

I would say that the opposite of this would be:

> Have you ever *not* paid a bill?

This asks if you ever knowingly neglected to pay a bill that was owing.

There are other aspects of the sentence that could be negated resulting in differing meanings, for example:

> Haven't you ever paid a bill?

or

> Have you never paid a bill?

These might be used to express some surprise that someone has never paid any bill.